# Hausdorff quasi-Polish spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, counterexamples

A topological space is said to be quasi-Polish if it is second-countable and completely quasi-metrizable (see for an introduction de Brecht's article: *de Brecht, Matthew*, [**Quasi-Polish spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.11.001), Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 164, No. 3, 356-381 (2013). [ZBL1270.03086](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1270.03086).) ).

These spaces have been introduced because, among other things, they allow the generalization of some results of classical descriptive set theory in non-Hausdorff environments. Now my question is:

- An Hausdorff quasi-Polish space needs to be Polish? Do we have a counter-example of an Hausdorff quasi-Polish space which is *not* Polish?

A strictly related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221405/hausdorff-open-image-of-a-polish-space), which asks basically the same thing, but is a bit old, so maybe there are new results that came up since then. Moreover, as the OP's comment points out, the question contained in Tkachuk's book is assuming all spaced Tychonoff and I'm not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that the following space $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is second-countable and quasi-Polish but not Polish.

Let $\mathbb Q$ be the field of rational numbners endowed with the discrete topology. Then its countable power $\mathbb Q^\omega$ is a Polish vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$. Let $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ be the projective space of $\mathbb Q$. So, $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is the quotient space of $\mathbb Q^\omega_\circ=\mathbb Q^\omega\setminus\{0\}^\omega$ by the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined as $x\sim y$ iff $\mathbb Qx=\mathbb Qy$. Is is easy to see that the quotient map $q:\mathbb Q^\omega_\circ\to P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is open, which implies that the space $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is second-countable. It is known that the space $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is Hausdorff but not Urysohn (moreover, $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is superconnected in the sense that for any nonempty open sets $U_1,\dots,U_n$ in $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ the intersection $\bar U_1\cap\dots\cap\bar U_n$ is not empty). Therefore, $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is not metrizable and hence not Polish.

Now we show that $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is quasi-Polish. Let $\mathbb Q^{<\omega}_\circ=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}(\mathbb Q^n\setminus\{0\}^n)$ be the countable set of all finite nonzero sequences of rational numbers and let $\{s_n\}_{n\in\omega}=\mathbb Q^{<\omega}_\circ$ be an enumeration of the set $\mathbb Q^{<\omega}_\circ$. For every sequence $s\in \mathbb Q^{<\omega}_\circ$ let $\ell(s)$ be its length and ${\uparrow}s=\{x\in\mathbb Q^\omega_\circ:x{\restriction}_{\ell(s)}=s\}$.
Let $q[{\uparrow}s]$ be the image of ${\uparrow}s$ under the quotient map $q:\mathbb Q^\omega_\circ\to P\mathbb Q^\omega$. It follows that $\{q[{\uparrow}s]:s\in\mathbb Q^\omega_\circ\}$ is a countable base of the topology of $P\mathbb Q^\omega$.

For every $n\in\omega$, consider the quasi-pseudometric
$d_n:P\mathbb Q^\omega\times P\mathbb Q^\omega\to\{0,1\}$ defined by $d_n{-1}(1)=q[{\uparrow}s_n]\times (P\mathbb Q^\omega\setminus q[{\uparrow}s_n])$.
Finally consider the quasi-metric $d:P\mathbb Q^\omega\times P\mathbb Q^\omega\to[0,1]$ defined by $$d=\sum_{n\in\omega}\tfrac1{2^{n+1}}d_n.$$
I hope that the quasi-metric $d$ witnesses that $P\mathbb Q^\omega$ is a quasi-Polish space.

Comment: From section 7 of the de Brecht paper mentioned in the question it follows that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous open surjection with $Y$ $T_0$ and $X$ Polish, then $Y$ is quasi-Polish. This should show that $P\Bbb Q^\omega$ is quasi-Polish without having to exhibit an explicit quasi-metric

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Ok. Thank you, but anyway to know a concrete quasi-metric can be helpful. Also with such a theorem, maybe a better (and more natural) example is the projective space $P\mathbb R^\omega$, as in https://mathoverflow.net/a/412185/61536

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but de Brecht's paper itself actually contains a simple counter-example just before lemma 72:

> let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real numbers with the usual topology, $K = \{1/n | n ∈ \omega, n \ge 1\}$, and $B = \mathbb{R} \setminus K$. Then $K \in \Delta^0_2(\mathbb{R})$ because it is countable and Polish, hence $B \in \Delta^0_2(\mathbb{R})$. The topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by adding $B$ as an open set, sometimes called the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$, is quasi-Polish by Lemma 71 and clearly Hausdorff, but it is not regular, hence not
> Polish, because $0$ and the closed set $K$ do not have disjoint neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2):

Some further examples of Hausdorff Quasi-Polish but not Polish spaces can be found in

Kihara, Ng & Pauly: Enumeration degrees and non-metrizable topology [arXiv 1904.04107](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04107)

In Example 3.17, we construct a Quasi-Polish version of the Arens Square[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04107), which is even $T_{2.5}$ but not completely Hausdorff. Another Quasi-Polish space in the $T_{2.5}$ yet not completely Hausdorff realm is the Quasi-Polish version of Roy's lattice space, in Proposition 5.13. A Quasi-Polish space which is $T_2$ but not $T_{2.5}$ is provided in Theorem 5.7 as a variant of the double-origin space.

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04107) First properly constructed over there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715435/is-arens-square-a-urysohn-space